# Square matrices: $(A+B)^2=A^2+B^2$

Tags: linear-algebra

If $a, b$ are two numbers such that $(a+b)^2 = a^2 + b^2$, then $a.b = 0$.

Is there a similar statement for square matrices.

"If $A, B$ are square matrices such that $(A+B)^2 = A^2 + B^2$, then $A.B = 0$."

Note that if $(A+B)^2 = A^2 + B^2$, then $AB = -BA$, hence $tr(AB) = 0$

Comment: If looks like you found the statement -- it's $AB+BA=0$.  

Comment: Unfortunately, this is not a good question for MO. It would better belong at math.stackexchange.com. I have voted to close. 

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If 
$$
  A=\begin{pmatrix} 
   0&M\\ M&0\end{pmatrix},\qquad 
  B =\begin{pmatrix}-I&0\\ 0&I\end{pmatrix}
$$
then $AB+BA=0$, so $A^2+B^2=(A+B)^2$ and neither $A$ nor $B$ is zero.

Comment: Thanks Chris Godsil. 
I forgot Quaternion group http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quaternion_group
$ij = -ji$